# Marquee-scroll delay

Tags: html, css, marquee

When the marquee-direction is backwards, text appears as soon as the text goes out from left end but when up the text goes out of top but does not immediately reappear from bottom.

```
#content {position:absolute;left:10%;top:25%;width:40%;height:50%;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;/* Safari and Chrome  */overflow-x:-webkit-marquee;-webkit-marquee-direction:up;-webkit-marquee-style: scroll;-webkit-marquee-speed: fast;-webkit-marquee-increment:small;-webkit-marquee-repetition:infinite;z-index:2;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mr.Gordon...

I check your css. Please make change on this:

```
    -webkit-marquee-style: slide;
    -webkit-marquee-increment:1px;
```

Check my link http://jsfiddle.net/eCH4J/1/

Good Luck !